# How to make upper and lower abs more visible

Tags: workout-routines, workout, abdominals

new guy here, and I greeting everyone in  Physical Fitness thread.
I have a question about my body.

On 20 December 2021, I started abs workout only until today.

**1.** I am doing every morning like 10 o clock abs workout different styles  ( with  **no** equipment and no weights) for about  5 minutes to 10 max. In the same day , night 23:00 I am doing another 5 to 10 minutes abs.

**2.** I use 2 "chairs" only  and I am doing different combinations of styles abs.

**3.** I sleep like 8 hours per day. Some days I sleep more than 8 hours to 10 hours and rare 12hours. I wrote this because I read here that sleep is important.

**4.** I didn't follow a proper way of nutritient diet. I take every night a couple of tea of rosemary. I ate sugar etc.With other words I didn't gave my attention on what I eating.

**Result**: its been like 4-5 weeks ( I am doing everyday only abs morning and night.) and I see that my abs are defined. More specific,

`my middle abs` : are visible. If I look straight with my eyes I see those 2  middle-abs.If I go to mirror I can see them too.It doesn't need I to try to tough my abs to be seem.I beleive are visible even when I am relaxed.

`upper abs`: are covered by body fat I can say.If I put my fingers I can feel those abs- I beleive that I don't hit those abs well.If I look in mirror it doesn't seem only if I turn my body to left or right I can see from the mirror that I can see something.

`lower abs` :  is like upper abs  but little more visible.

If I make tought my abs I can see a six pack **define** but it has body fat on upper and lower abs.Less body fat in middle abs.From left side or right side if i mirror myself I can see  the 6 abs.
Before the 4 weeks my six pack didn't seemed nor my middle abs as much as today.

any idea how to do upper/lower abs been seemed?

Comment: What's your body fat percentage like?

Comment: @alec not sure.Based on this link https://www.omnicalculator.com/health/body-fat i am 20%

Comment: ok my body fat based    https://www.calculator.net/body-fat-calculator.html                     is 22.6%  and BMI 18.8%. Which one of those is?

Comment: Just FYI, "upper" and "lower" abs isn't really a thing. It's all one muscle.

Comment: @JohnP thanks for your comment ,but the middle abs are more visible than other parts which is all one thing

Comment: @maikl - Yeah, that's an indication of how your fat is distributed, and not really an indication that one part of the abs is more developed than another.

Comment: @Alec thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Someone once said,

> If you can't see your abs, you're still fat

Abdominal fat is usually the last one to go. If you want to make your abs more visible you need to drop a couple more body fat percentage. I'd track the macros and calories for a few days and use some sort of [macro calculator](https://www.calculator.net/macro-calculator.html) to come up with a caloric deficit for a few weeks.

If you really believe you're around 20% body fat I'd try dropping it at least to 15% first, then check if you're satisfied or need to go further. Different people will see abs at different body percentages, so there's no one specific number for everyone.

Comment: if I tighting my abs stomach area I can feel and see the shape of 6 pack with some body fat around it. If I am relaxed I can see ONLY the middle abs. If I touch my lower abs or up and press inside I feel the abs.I don't think is issue of body fat. If it was how is possible that I can see my middle abs and not upper .

Comment: I beleive I need workouts to hit those areas or something else..that's what I am asking or if something goes wrong with my abs

Comment: @maikl I don't think there's something wrong with your abs; people just have different shaped muscles. Middle section will usually be visible sooner, but keep getting leaner and the rest should pop. Exercise alone won't get you there, you need to get leaner.